# How could I recreate the iOS app switcher with UIScrollView and UIPageControl

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have 9 views with 5 57x57 UIButtons on them. I want to be able to scroll and page through them like with the iOS app switcher.

My xib is set up like so:

[image]

Each page's view is set up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cocoacontrols.com

One of these might get you started...

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check some of these out.